# blocked.com integration with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to integrate blocked.com in my Laravel 5.2 setup but I don't want to add the blocked.com script in my public folder. I have kept the scripts in app/Libraries folder. Now the issue is to open a PHP file from that folder (from outside public folder).

I am trying this

```
Route::get('/block-det', [function () {
    return redirect()->to('../app/Libraries/blockscript/detector.php');
}]);
```

But it's redirecting me to https://example.com/app/Libraries/blockscript/index.php

Answer (score 0):

`redirect` redirects you to a new url, which is why you get redirected to the url you pasted above.  You simply want to call that php file.  You can do so using `require`:

```
Route::get('/block-det', function() {
    require '../app/Libraries/blockscript/detector.php';
});
```

Depending on the location of `detector.php` you may need to change the path.

Also, it is much more typical, if you are pulling in 3rd party code, to use composer to pull it in, then it is automatically installed in the vendor folder and you can access it from your app that way.